# How do I force a PDF to fully download before being viewed?

Tags: android, pdf, mobile, download

I highly suspect the solution to a problem I am having developing a mobile website is to prevent the PDF from downloading in parts.  Downloading a PDF from this mobile site on Android results in download unsuccessful.

The site is on a staging server that requires simple authentication. I have read elsewhere that Android doesn't handle this situation properly (or at least there have been multiple similar issues). If I can simply get the file to download fully without it being sent in small packets my hunch is that the issue I am encountering will go away.

How do I force a PDF to fully download before being viewed?

Other ideas on this topic are desired as well!

Comment: Do you have control over PDF generation?

Comment: Yes. I have been experimenting with the options but I am not sure there is one specific to progressive downloading.

Comment: your pdfs seem linearized see http://www.citationsoftware.com/faqPDFlinearization.htm for explanation on linearization. What library are you using for generation?

Comment: Good to know its called "linearized" to allow for partial download. This page doesn't say however how or whether it can be prevented by Acrobat Pro which I am using. The very first thing I did when attempting to solve this problem was to uncheck "optimize for fast web download" which did not work, but I will investigate further.

Comment: What you're doing should in fact help. In the PDF specification the feature is called "Linearization", but the options in the UI of Acrobat and Distiller are in fact called "Optimize for fast web view" because that is what the feature was invented for. It's also an old feature, has been around since PDF 1.2 so it's surprising it wouldn't work. Generally (that may help find you why you didn't succeed) you'd have to do a full save as on an existing PDF as turning the feature off will require rewriting of the complete file...